# Winsock recv() does not block

Tags: c++, winsock

I have just compiled this code:
http://www.win32developer.com/tutorial/winsock/winsock_tutorial_2.shtm

I have added some codes so it does recv(), in an infinite loop. My problem, if there is no data to read, it still does not block.

Am I totally mistaken if I think recv should block in my case?

The code I have added is:

```
for(;;)
{
  char buffer[1000];
  memset(buffer,0,999);
  int inDataLength = recv(Socket,buffer,1000,0);

  int nError=WSAGetLastError();
  if(nError!=WSAEWOULDBLOCK&&nError!=0)
  {
    std::cout<<"Winsock error code: "<<nError<<"\r\n";
    std::cout<<"Client disconnected!\r\n";

    // Shutdown our socket
    shutdown(Socket,SD_SEND);

    // Close our socket entirely
    closesocket(Socket);

    break;
  }
}
```

It is at the end, after the `std::cout<<"Client connected!\r\n\r\n";` line.
I know I copied this from a "non blocking" example, but I dont think this code should do anything nonblocking really, still, my for loop is running like mad!

Comment: Could you paste the additional code you've written?

Comment: Are you using any WSAsync... calls?

Comment: What kind of client do you have connecting to your server?

Comment: @chrisaycock: I connect to it via php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if((nError == SOCKET_ERROR) || (nError == 0))
    WSAGetLastError();
else
    ; // handle success
```

That's how it should look, and not how you did it.

Comment: Just to clarify: 'WSAEWOULDBLOCK' is good for **non-blocking** sockets. And, you should check WSAGetLastError() ONLY if the return code was 'SOCKET_ERROR' (-1).

Comment: @Rob: How does nError get it's value then if i do not use WSAGetLastError()?

Comment: @Poni: Sorry I meant Poni, not Rob.

Comment: Easy Mike, see nError in its first usage (after the call to recv()) as in indicator - "did an error happen at all? if so, I should see what it is". And so it is, if nError, at first, would indicate that something went wrote then you just use WSAGetLastError() which will give extended info, and nError can take its value, making it to its second stage. If not using nError for the value returned by WSAGetLastError() then no problem, then nError was just an indicator. See next comment within a minute, I'll send you to the right page.

Comment: Here, check the "Return Value" clause: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740121%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: As you see it means you got **three possible situations** after calling recv(); 1) Success. 2) Error by getting a reply of zero. 3) Error by getting a reply of 'SOCKET_ERROR'.

Comment: `SOCKET_ERROR` is returned by `recv()`, not by `WSAGetLastError()`.  The code should be checking `inDataLength` first and then calling `WSAGetLAstError()` only if `inDataLength == SOCKET_ERROR`.

Comment: That's not how it should look at all. Why would `nError` ever be zero? And what is the point of getting it again but throwing it away?

Answer (score 6):

`recv` should block by default, unless there's a socket error or you explicitly set the socket to non-blocking. Be sure to check the return value for error. For more information see the Microsofts MSDN article on [recv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740121%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The loop is not checking for errors correctly.  It needs to be more like this instead:

```
char buffer[1000]; 
int inDataLength;

do 
    {
    inDataLength = recv(Socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0); 
    if (inDataLength > 0)
        {
        // inDataLength number of bytes were received, use buffer as needed...
        continue;
        }

    if (inDataLength == 0)
        {
        std::cout << "Client disconnected!" << std::endl; 
        break;
        }

    int nError = WSAGetLastError(); 
    if (nError != WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
        {
        std::cout << "Winsock error code: " << nError << std::endl; 
        break;
        }

    // optionally call select() here to wait for the socket
    // to receive data before calling recv() again...
    /*
    fd_set fd;
    FD_ZERO(&fd);
    FD_SET(Socket, &fd);

    timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = ...;
    tv.tv_usec = ...;

    nError = select(Socket+1, &fd, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    if (nError == 0)
        {
        std::cout << "Timeout waiting for data" << std::endl; 
        break;
        }

    if (nError == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
        nError = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cout << "Winsock error code: " << nError << std::endl; 
        break;
        }
    */
    } 
while (true);

// Shutdown our socket 
shutdown(Socket, SD_SEND); 

// Close our socket entirely 
closesocket(Socket);
```