# C++ Winsock recv not blocking

Tags: c++, winsock

I'm devleoping a server in c++ and when im using recv() in a while loop it returns all the time length of -1 and also continue the loop without blocking.

```
while(true)
{
   char buffer[1024];
   int dataLength =  recv(socket, buffer, 1024, 0)
   cout << dataLength;
}
```

output: -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1.............

Anyone knows how to make this socket to block until it recievs data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does WSAGetLastError return?

Comment: With help from the thread given by the answer below I managed to print what WSAGetLastError and it returns 10057

Comment: `WSAENOTCONN
10057 (0x2749)
A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied.` - [System Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681391(v=vs.85).aspx) - Learn to love 'em.

Comment: Thanks but I'm using tcp and datagram sockets it;s udp no? My socket is construct like this Socket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);. By the way the client side is in c# using TcpClient there maybe a competibility issue?

Comment: Did you ever call `connect`? Is there an error from that?

Comment: This is the server should I call connect?

Comment: My bad, it shouldn't. Did you do all of the steps listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530751(v=vs.85).aspx) and check for when the first error arises?

Comment: Since this is a server socket, you have to call `accept()`, THEN you call `recv()` on the `SOCKET` that `accept()` returns. Do not call `recv()` on the listening `SOCKET`.

Comment: No I did not did every step on this tutorial but I checked every call on initialization I think and everyone except recv where returned 0. But then I have to to this for every client which are connected to the server no?

Answer (score 2):

maybe there is an error during initilization
try calling GetLastError() and printing the result after each call

Answer (score 0):

As James suggested, check if a socket error occured. `recv()`s default behaviour is to block. See also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159158/c-winsock-recv-does-not-block) here.