# C++ TCP Winsock Server receiving the same packet many times

Tags: java, c++, sockets, tcp, winsock

I have written a very simple C++ server which I am connecting to from a Java application.  The C++ server uses winsock2.  I am sending UTF8 encoded numbers to the server from my client and on receipt of these numbers I would like the server to perform an action.  However my server seems to be receiving a series of numbers as one.  At the moment I have the server listening every 1 millisecond for a new message.

This is my C++ server code which receives the message:

```
  bool receive()
     {
          char buffer[1024];
          int inDataLength=recv(Socket,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);
          if(buffer[0] != '\0')
          {
                     std::cout<<"Client: ";
                     std::cout << buffer;
                     sendKey(string(buffer));  
          }
          else if (inDataLength == 0) //Properly closed connection
          {
             std::cout<<"Connection lost..\r\n";
             return false;
          }    
          return true;
     }
```

This is called within a loop like so:

```
 while ( receive() )
{
      Sleep(1);
}
```

This is my java client code to send a message where out is `OutputStream = socket.getOutputStream():`

```
public void send(String msg)
{
        try {
            out.write( msg.getBytes("UTF8") );
            out.flush();
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            Global.error("Connection error..");
            //e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Global.error("Never connected..\r\n");
        } catch (Exception e)
        { Global.error("Sending failed..\r\n"); }
    }
```

What I am getting is the server receiving for example the number 1, then 2, then 12, then 121 etc.. in no specific pattern except once the server is receiving 2 numbers at once it will never start receiving only one again.  This is the only place in my java code where anything is sent to the server and I flush the buffer after each message so I think the issue is on my server but I'm at a loss as to the problem.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Log the calls to send. Can it be a problem in generating the strings? And what is the reason for the sleeps?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have logged the calls to send in the my application (removed them in the example), they are only called when expected and not repeating.  Also the sleep on the server is because the loop was maxing out the cpu and the sleeps on the java application is to be on par (or in this case slower) then the server reads.

Comment: I should confess that winsock was a long time ago for me, and but recv should be blocking. What happens if you only send one message from the client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are forgetting the most important check:

```
int inDataLength=recv(Socket,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);
if (inDataLength == -1 ) {
    std::cerr << "receive error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    return false;
}
...
```

This actually might be the reason your loop took so much CPU time.

Comment: He should also check for EOS, an even more likely cause of the infinite loop.

Comment: I think he does: `else if (inDataLength == 0) //Properly closed connection`

Comment: Agreed. However he should check it before checking the buffer contents, not after, and he should close the socket when he sees it.

Answer (score 0):

Given the sleeps it seems as the recv is not blocking.. Take a look at [Winsock recv() does not block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159158/c-winsock-recv-does-not-block). You need to check for errors in the return value.

Comment: I would add that you need to check the return value before you check buffer. Given that your buffer is not the stack and you did not set/clear it (using something like memset), whatever value is in buffer (which are value which were on the stack) may cause your first if to execute, even if you did not receive any data.  Check inDataLength values first (including error conditions) before checking the buffer.

Comment: More likely the sleeps are just literally a waste of time. Novices tend to litter network code with sleeps in vain attempts to make them work better.