# winsock recv() always returning -1

Tags: tcp, winsock, recv, proxy-server

Hi im doing a proxy server and whenever I use this recv() loop from here: [Winsock recv() does not block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159158/winsock-recv-does-not-block)
the recv() function always returns -1, so it exits the loop and never got to receive anything.

```
int System::receive(SOCKET &recvSocket)
{
    char buffer[4096] = { 0 };
    int numBytes;


    do {
        numBytes = recv(recvSocket, buffer, 4095, 0);
        //lastReceived = lastReceived + buffer; 
        //get recent contents of buffer
        cout << numBytes << endl;
        if (numBytes > 0)
        {
            cout << buffer << endl;
            continue;
        }

        if (numBytes == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Client disconnected!" << std::endl;
            break;
        }

        int nError = WSAGetLastError();
        cout << nError << endl;
        if (nError != WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
        {
            std::cout << "Winsock error code: " << nError << std::endl;
            break;
        }


    } while (1);

    return numBytes;
}
```

calling the code at main with non blocking socket:

```
SOCKET establishedConn = Server.acceptSocket(listenSocket);
u_long iMode = 1;
if (establishedConn != NULL) {

    ioctlsocket(establishedConn, FIONBIO, &iMode);
     Server.receive(establishedConn); //receive request from client
}
```

Is there any reason why its not returning anything?

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't provided the value of `nError` it is impossible to be sure, but it is probably EWOULDBLOCK, meaning there is no data, which is almost inevitable given that you have the socket in non-blocking mode and you aren't using `select()` and you're reading in a hard loop.

Either restructure your receive method to use non-blocking mode properly, or leave it as is and use blocking mode, which seems to be your intention anyway given the code structure.